# Loading all properties from vault before the application start-node js

Tags: node.js, api

Trying to integrate vault for secret management in an existing application based on NodeJs.
In app.js I am invoking the vault service as given below

```
    async function main () {
    const secrets = await vaultSecretService.fetchSecrets();
    console.log('secrets from vault--', JSON.stringify(secrets));
    ---
     ---
    }
    
    (async function() {
      await main();
      })();
require(path.join(__dirname, '/models/db'));
```

Since the service methods are async how can I make sure that all the secrets are loaded before invoking my db.js, where it is expecting db credentials from vault.

Answer (score 0):

Since your current code already `await`s loading/fetching the secrets, you can just move the `require` after that:

```
 async function main () {
    const secrets = await vaultSecretService.fetchSecrets();
    console.log('secrets from vault--', JSON.stringify(secrets));
    require(path.join(__dirname, '/models/db'));
    // rest of your code
 }
```

Comment: @ANP: any feedback?